# Is it possible to dynamically populate Angular 2 Material Tabs with a For Loop Subscribe?

Tags: html, angular, for-loop, tabs, angular-material

I need to populate a dynamic amount of Tabs on an Angular 2 site using a For Loop that is using a subscribe to get data from a database service and I am wondering if it is even possible.

My data set is broken down by Classes: A, B and C and they each have a Sub-Class of 1 and 2. So I would like to have my results dynamically create 3 tabs (Tab A, Tab B, and Tab C). So far I have this working.

I then need each of these tabs to then display the data of their Sub-Classes. As of now the loop runs the 3 times and provides the data needed but every page just shows data for Class C as it was the last one to run and the model is updated with all of its data.

Below is what I have thus far.

**classdata.component.html**

```html
<mat-tab-group>
<mat-tab *ngFor="let classresult of classresults;" label="Class -{{classresult.Class_Name}}">
<table class ="responstable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sub-Class Name</th>
<th>Value</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let subclassresult of subclassresults;">
<td>{{subclassresult.Sub_Class_Name}}  </td>
<td>{{subclassresult.Value}}  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**classdata.component.ts**

```js
   // Populate Class Level Data
   this.databaseService.getClass()
   .subscribe(classresults => this.classresults = classresults,
    error => console.log('ERROR!'),
    // Populate Sub-Class Level Data
    () => { for (const classresult of this.classresults) {
      this.selectedClassId = classresult.Class_ID;
      console.log(this.selectedClassId);
      this.databaseService.getSubClass(this.selectedClassId)
      .subscribe(subclassresults => this.subclassresults = subclassresults);
    }
  }
  );
```

**database.service.ts**

```js
getClass(): Observable<ClassResult[]> {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/c';
  const data = ({
  });
  return this._http.post(url, data)
  .pipe(
    map((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return <ClassResult[]> res;
    })
  );
}


getSubClass(Class_ID): Observable<SubClassResult[]> {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/sc';
  const data = ({
    classid: Class_ID
  });
  return this._http.post(url, data)
  .pipe(
    map((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return <SubClassResult[]> res;
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching each Subclass for every parentClass but you are reassigning each result to the class variable `this.subclassresults`. Basically you are overwriting each previous result with the current result. Thats why every page just shows data for Class C.

There are many different solutions how you can solve this problem.

On solution could be you are using `forkJoin` Observable and save the result of your parentClass with their subClasses in their own object:

```js
this.databaseService.getClass().pipe(
  switchMap(classResults => {
    const subClassRequests = classResults.map(
      classResult => this.dabaseService
        .getSubClass(classResult)
        .pipe(map(subClassResults => {classResult, subClassResults}))
       )
       return forkJoin(subClassRequests)
  })
).subscribe(results => this.results = results);
```

`results` holds your data as an array.

And in your template use it like this:

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let result of results;" label="Class -{{result.classresult.Class_Name}}">
    <table class ="responstable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Sub-Class Name</th>
          <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let subclassresult of result.subclassresults;">
          <td>{{subclassresult.Sub_Class_Name}}  </td>
          <td>{{subclassresult.Value}}  </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**I implemented a small working Demo:** [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gcjf1f)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to put this together. I am trying to implement it but am having some issues.

Both my getClass and getSubClass require variables like:

getClass(x, x, x) and getSubClass(classid, x, x, x)

These variables are passed to the database to be used in their respective queries. Will this cause complications? Sorry for not including in my OP but I didn't think they would cause issue.

Comment: This should be no problem. Which issues are you facing?

Comment: My linter is showing the following:

Argument of type '(subclassreslts: Observable<SubClassResult[]>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<SubClassResult[]>, Observable<{}>>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<{}>'.
[ts] Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.

Comment: I updated my answer. I forgot a map operator at databaseService.getSubClasses()

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me -- I am now getting the following errors:

ts(101,49): error TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
 error TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'ClassDataComponent'.

Comment: It isn't a lot but I will send you $5 via paypal if we can get this working. I have been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: I can only help if I can see the actual code or at least the component with his dependencies